# Error in connecting to secured websocket

Tags: linux, node.js, websocket

I am trying to connect with secured websocket using nodejs using ws library.Server is also using same ws library.

My ios and chrome webapp is able to connect to secured websocket 
But as soon as I am trying to connect through a Linux based system the error thrown:

```
events.js:74
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1289:32)
    at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:94:17)
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:896:10)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:430:15)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:304:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:344:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:250:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:237:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:184:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:557:24)
```

My code snippet is:

```
/*Websocket client ; gateway will intiate the connection to cloud*/
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var connection_client = new WebSocket('wss://IP:1337/macadd=' + process.argv[2] +'&platform=gateway'
);
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`CERT_UNTRUSTED` may mean you are using a self-signed certificate that has not been trusted. Put the same certificate for HTTPS and WSS so the browser can prompt the user for trusting it.

Comment: No i bought certificate from godday and using same certificate for https also.
and if i was using a self signed certificate then mobile app and web app should also promted for cert_untrusted.
Error which i can think of: like browsers have pre installed CA Goodady certificate ,so by matching with my Ca certificate they can trust my certificate where as it may possible that node js written client in linux may not having any way to check my ca certificate..is this make sense??